# how can i start a new rails 7 project with bootstrap5 and jquery support

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I need to create a rails7.3.1 project with bootstrap latest.But, heard that Jquery will not support with latest bootstrap.
Also, I am planing to download the latest bootstrap files as part of my rails project.Which location  I need to include these CSS files and script files in rails7 ?
Please give some guidance to start the project with some initial UI page for login.

Comment: Why would you use jquery in a new project?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery was deleted only from Bootstrap, I think you still can use the `jquery-rails` gem to use it. Also, you don't need to add bootstrap files manually to your project. Just use the `bootstrap` gem.

Check this guide https://rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap/5.3.2